# double "and" SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I am working on an SQL query for the following table:

```
product_id | type | value
1 | gender  | female
1   | age   |  1-10
2   | gender    | female
2 | age |  1-10
3   | gender    | male
3 | age  | 11-20
4   | gender     | female
4   | age    | 11-20
5   | gender    | male
5   | age   | 1-10
```

A product (different table, product_id is foreign key) has attributes of type gender or age. I would like to get distinct product ids for the case where both gender = female and age = 1-10.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT distinct product_id 
FROM Attributes 
WHERE (type = "gender" and value  ="female") 
  and (type = "age" and value = "1-10")
```

I would expect to get back product ids 1 and 2. However I get back nothing.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `"female"` denotes a column name in standard SQL, not a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because there are no rows that have both a type of Gender AND a type of Age. I would go with a subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM Attributes WHERE (type = "age" and value ="1-10") 

AND product_ID IN (

SELECT distinct product_id FROM Attributes WHERE (type = "gender" and value ="female"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that anything in the sample table is both

```
(type = "gender" and value ="female") and (type = "age" and value = "1-10")
```

I think that this inner join on a sub-selection might work though:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.product_id 
FROM Attributes A 
INNER JOIN A.product_id = B.product_id
  (
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM Attributes 
    WHERE (type = "age" and value = "1-10") 
  ) B

WHERE (A.type = "gender" and A.value ="female")
```

That should be a list of distinct product IDs where gender is female, and the age is "1-10"